# How can I open VS code "in container" without it restarting itself and losing shell settings when "Reopen in container" is invoked?

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code, vscode-remote

I have a development use-case where I use a script to configure a shell with docker-machine or other environment and then open a directory containing source and settings (/.vscode/*, .devcontainer/*) that I can edit/build/debug in the [VS code Remote Containers](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/remote-overview) extension.

In short, I'm looking to implement the [following sequence](https://github.com/aniongithub/devcontainer-tools/blob/master/devcontainer/templates/default/post-activate#L10) when a "start-development.sh" script/hook runs:

1. Set up host-side env or remote resources (reverse sshfs to mount source to a remote docker-machine, modprobe, docker buildx, xhost for x-passthrough, etc.)
2. Run VS Code **in that shell so settings aren't thrown away** with a specified directory (may be mounted via sshfs or other means) in container, not just open on the host
3. Run cleanup scripts to clean-up and/or destroy real resources (unmount, modprobe -r, etc.) when the development container is stopped (by either closing VS Code or rebuilding the container).

See [this](https://github.com/aniongithub/devcontainer-tools/blob/master/examples/aws/.devcontainer/aws/post-activate) script for a simple example of auto-configuring a shell with an AWS instance via docker-machine. I'll be adding a few more examples to this repository over the coming day or so.

It's easy enough to open VS Code in that directory (`code -w -n --folder-uri /path/here`) and wait for it to quit (so I can perform cleanup steps like taking down the remote docker-machine, un-mounting reverse-sshfs mounted code or disabling kernel mods I use for development, etc.).

However, VS code currently opens in "host mode" and when I choose "Reopen in container" or "Rebuild container" via the UI or command palette, it kills that process and opens another top-level(?) process, quitting the shell & throwing away my configuration and/or prematurely running my cleanup portion of the script so it has the wrong env. when it finally launches in-container. Sadness.

So finally, my question is:

Is there a way to tell VS code to open a folder "in-container"? This would solve a ton of problems for me, instead of a janky dev. cycle where I have to ensure that the code instance isn't restarting itself and messing things up - whenever I rebuild the container, for example.

Alternatively, it'd be great to not quit the top-level `code` process I started altogether, enabling me to wait on that, or perhaps monitor it in other ways I'm not aware of to prevent erasure of my settings and premature run of my cleanup script?

Thanks in advance!

*PS: Please read the entire question before flagging it as "not related to development". If the idea of a zero-install development environment for a complex native project, live on-device development/debugging or deep learning using cloud instances with giant GPUs for Docker where you don't have to manually manage everything and write pages of readmes appeals to you - this is very much about programming.*

Comment: `https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/containers#_attached-container-configuration-files` it says you can use  `"workspaceFolder": "/path/to/code/in/container/here",`. 
Didn't do anything like this myself. that article also says that you can use your Dockerfile. which allows you to define default folder like this `WORKDIR /app`.

i don't see a way to control how VS is attaching to container. but in docker you can start new container with infinite command inside like `sleep infinity`. and then run extra processes from outside by doing `docker exec -it [container-name] bash`

Comment: I'm aware of workspaceFolder and other parameters in devcontainer.json, but that doesn't help my situation unfortunately. As for launch/attach, that's almost exactly how VS code does things as well. In addition it runs a VS code server inside the container which the client connects to to provide IDE functionality. I'm interested in hooking the start/stop of this correctly to do host side setup, development and teardown automatically.

Comment: I chose to use a docker-compose.yml for another reason. It was a good way to introduce a "layer" on top of the "user's" Dockerfile by introducing a dependency between "services". See here for an example - https://github.com/aniongithub/devcontainer-tools/blob/master/examples/aws/.devcontainer/aws/docker-compose.yml. I have all the docker bits down, it's VS Code's client process management and environment wrangling I'm trying to decipher.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After all weekend of trying different things, I finally figured it out! The key was [this](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/containers-advanced#_developing-inside-a-container-on-a-remote-docker-host) section in the awesome articles about advanced container configuration.

I put that into a bash script and used `jq` to merge `docker.host` and other `docker env` settings into `.vscode/settings.json`. See this example [here](https://github.com/aniongithub/devcontainer-tools/blob/58b5ecd114f4281966b1f2add602ec436201e74a/commands.txt#L32).

After running a script that generates this file, the user will only need to reload/relaunch VS code in that workspace folder (where the settings were created) and yay, everything works as expected.

I plan to add some actual samples now that I have the basics working. Unfortunately, I had to separate my `create` and `teardown` as separate `activate` and `deactivate` hooks. Not a bad workflow still, IMO.